# Informix ODBC Connection String Password Special Characters Fail

Tags: windows, powershell, odbc, informix

I have a requirement to use special characters in an Informix ODBC connection string from within a Powershell script. The password should match the users Windows password. Several ODBC related posts suggest using braces {...} to protect the password, but this does not work.

I'm using Informix ODBC driver 3.34 32BIT

The following connection string with a simple password works:

$conn.connectionstring = "DSN=PD7333;Uid=generic;Pwd=readonly;"

This does not work.
"DSN=PD7333;Uid=generic;Pwd={readonly};"

Any suggestions to protect special characters in an Informix ODBC connection string?

Comment: Have you experimented with single quotes around the password?  Double quotes (which would need to be escaped so that they actually appear in the connection string.

Comment: No luck.  "DSN=PD7333;Uid=generic;Pwd='readonly';"

Comment: It may make no difference but why not try with a more recent ODBC driver (e.g 4.10.TC14). Informix ODBC 3.34 is ancient (I think it belongs to CSDK 2.60 or 2.70 which is really really old)